# How to properly remove cache for my customers

Tags: wordpress, caching, cloudflare, elementor

**Let's start with my environment :**

- Wordpress (Elementor - Optimized by Siteground extension only)
- Hosted on Siteground
- CDN Cloudflare (free edition — Cache ttl set to 4h)

**My test routine :**

- On my computer, I change the top bar color on my client website (https://www.sandorina.fr — if you want to see cache configuration)
- On my phone, I reload my browser

**The problem :**

The topbar color doesn't change and keep its old one.

**Workaround :**

I can see my modification by purging Cloudflare cache & my phone browser cache (via chrome inspect devices).

**So what ?**

My client has more and more customers on her website. In order to optimize it, I make dailies updates. However, it's very frustrating to see that my changes aren't refresh (for weeks, or more), and even more for the customers (I make retargeting so...). And I can't say to them : "oh, you just have to clean your phone cache". I've many gaps regarding caching and hosting configuration and your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to clear cache manually via Cloudflare dashboard.
Just navigate to your website inside the Cloudflare Dashboard >> Caching >> Configuration >> Purge Everything. Please note that changes take effects only after few seconds.